# Emulate PHP's explode( ) with Javascript's .split( )

Tags: javascript, php

For basic use, these functions work the same. Split an input string into an array based on an extra string. Both also take an extra "limit" variable.

However, in PHP, the limit means that after you've matched *limit* items, the entire rest of the string does into the last item of the array. This is actually quite useful.

JS's limit means that once your return array has *limit* many items, it just stops adding items to it. This implementation of limit is kind of useless, and also easily emulated with other array functions.

So is there an easy way to emulate PHP's way with JS?

Consider the following as the input string:

`$str = "7,43,This is a long sentence, know what I mean?";`

I'd want `$str.split(",",3);` to return this array:

`{"7","43","This is a long sentence, know what I mean?"}`

Comment: The classic question: What you have tried ?

Comment: I'm not good at js but split on comma and implode array items 2->x, should be simple enough

Answer (score 4):

Using [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
const s = "7,43,This is a long sentence, know what I mean?"

function explode(delimiter, str, limit) {
  const data = str.split(delimiter);
  return [...data.splice(0, limit - 1), data.join(delimiter)];
}

const res = explode(',', s, 3);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: If your emulating PHP, you just have your parameters the wrong way round.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, using [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) should do what you want:

```js
function explode(char, str, limit) {
    let a = str.split(char);
    return a.slice(0, limit-1).concat(a.slice(limit-1).join(char));
}

let str = "7,43,This is a long sentence, know what I mean?";

console.log(explode(',', str, 3));
```